# ADB Change a parameter ( resolution , iso-values ... ) with android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: shell, adb

I'm writing you about ADB. I'm trying to send a command with ADB to change the resolution, iso-value ... with ADB before take a picture with ADB :

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

Do you know if a command of adb shell to change the parameter of camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` this action will launch the camera app if present in the device.

Whether to accept extra data from the user/command depends on the camera app. As far I know device default camera app doesn't support extra data like resolution, iso values. That should be set by the user manually.